# distinct, max and group by query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, subquery, distinct

I have a dataset like:

```
list1     list2   
a          e
a          e
b          w
a          e
a          r
b          c
```

I want to find most frequent item in list2 grouped by list1.

```
list1     list2    max
  a         e       3
  b         w       1
```

How can I get rid of the equal number of elements like b,w,1 and b,c,1 ?
I want to have one of them at random.

I tried something like this

```
SELECT clf1 as clf2, first(value_count) as max_value 
FROM (SELECT list1 as clf1, list2, count(list2) AS value_count FROM table GROUP BY list2,clf1 order by value_count desc) 
GROUP BY clf2
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer may depend on the product used.)

Comment: @jarlh I  am using mssql

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query:

**Q1:**

```
SELECT list1, count(list2) AS value_count FROM table GROUP BY list1;
```

This will give you all `list1` existance;

**Q2:**

```
`SELECT list1, max(list2), count(list2) AS value_count FROM table GROUP BY list1,list2`;
```

This will give you all `list1`existance only with `max(list2)`.

Comment: It is not correct, It will show `a|e|4` for the first row

Comment: @RadimBača your discussion is right.So i have updated my query as your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select list1 , List2 , count(List2)  AS value_count
From table Group By list1 , List2
```

Comment: It is not correct. It will show more than two rows. For example row `a|r|1` will be there.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code-only answers are not considered to be a good style. Please add 1-2 sentences and explain why and how this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
Select list1 , List2 , count(List2)  AS value_count
From table Group By list1 , List2
```

Comment: It is not correct. It will show more than two rows. For example row, `a|r|1` will be there

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to find most frequent item in list2 grouped by list1. Below script will work.

```
SELECT  top(1) [list1]
      ,[list2],
      count(*) as max
  FROM [dbo].[tableData]
  group by list1,list2
  order by max desc
```

Comment: But the user just need one (most frequent item)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are using Mysql, I think you could try a query like this one.

In the inner part of the query, ordinary count(*)/group by is made, ordering the results in descending order of count.

In the second part, I made a CROSS JOIN to initialize variables and define a CASE using variables to simulate ROW_NUMBER().

In the outer part results are filtered (only one row for each "group").

```
SELECT list1, list2, RC
FROM (SELECT A.*
    , CASE WHEN @gr1=list1 THEN @row_n:=@row_n+1 ELSE @row_n:=1 END AS RN 
    , @gr1:=list1    
    FROM (SELECT list1
             , list2
            , COUNT(*) AS RC
          FROM LIST 
          GROUP BY list1, list2
          ORDER BY list1, RC DESC ) A
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_n:=1, @gr1:='') B      
    ) C
WHERE RN=1;
```

Output:

```
list1   list2   RC
a       e       3
b       w       1
```